# Limit of Recurrent Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}_n^{\infty}, \{b_n\}_n^{\infty}$ be sequences of nonnegative numbers
and $0 \leq q < 1$, so that
$$
a_{n+1} \leq qa_n + b_n, \quad\text{for all}\quad n \geq 0.
$$
Prove that

- (i) If $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} b_n = 0$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n = 0.$
- (ii) If $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n<\infty,$ then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n<\infty$.

Comment: This question (1) gives orders and (2) does not indicate what the OP tried and where the OP is stuck. The other way round would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

(i) Try to find an equivalent series for $a_n$, note that $b_n \to 0$ implies that $b_n$ is bounded (why?), and combine these results to find that $a_n$ is dominated by a geometric series.

(ii) Use the expansion from (i) to derive that some multiple of $\sum_n b_n$ dominates $\sum_n a_n$.